# Error in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am having some annoying error in xcode 6.1 for storyboard.
Also not able to open storyboard to make changes.
any idea How to Fix it?[image: I had attach error of screen]

Comment: you could open storyboard with sourceCode and see error on line 14697 :)

Comment: check  in view controller line No **14697** the tag is mismatched

Comment: This could be and xml parsing error. Check for the line no. 14697 in storyboard source code.

Comment: checking my source code working on it.but file is too big and find exactly error on line 14955

Comment: otherwise open the file in a normal text editor like sublime, maybe that can handle a large file easier and also you have the ability to jump directly to that line...

Comment: or post the lines around 14955 here, maybe we can take a look at it as well

Comment: @PallaviLigade does it work out?

Comment: No. I revert back my changes..:(.. with previous

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the storyboard and chose `Open as --> Source Code`, then you can go to line 14955 and chase the error :)

[image]

Comment: :: Thanks, but repeated answer, already suggested by  Huy Nghia

Comment: no problem :) is it possible that Huy only added her answer as a comment? maybe you should notify her to suggest the same in the answer so that she can get points for it :) @PallaviLigade

Comment: @PallaviLigade could you please tick the green checkmark to mark the answer as solved? :)